# Polyglossia automated direction detection

Tags: polyglossia, bidi

Minimal ex:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}
دونالد كنوث هو Donald Knuth
\end{document}
```

Output: Donald Knuth name is reversed.

[image]

Fix: `دونالد كنوث هو \textenglish{Donald Knuth}`

From [Overleaf documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multilingual_typesetting_on_Overleaf_using_polyglossia_and_fontspec):

> the compiler treats differentiation as right-to-left text, as if it were a sequence of Arabic characters...

Question: is there a way for automated direction recognition (e.g: can it be done by pandoc: `.md` -> `.tex`)?

Comment: XeTeX or LuaTeX? AFAIK, it’s not possible with XeTeX. With LuaTeX it’s certainly possible, as the following example (using `babel`) demonstrates: https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/main/samples/lua-arabic.tex ; https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/main/samples/lua-arabic.pdf

Comment: @JavierBezos yeah, looks like LuaTex is better at handling Arabic than XeTex. This is a better option despite having to use similar commands like: `\foreignlanguage{english}{\textit{The Structure and
    Distribution of Coral Reefs}}\\[1ex]`